# We could not save your changes. Please try again. - Error message when uploading apk to Google Play

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried multiple times to upload my .apk and also an older .apk to Google Play.  It uploads, I see numbers going up to 100% for the uploading, then says processing and then:

- Upload error (top of screen message)
- We could not save your changes. Please try again. (message above upload button)
- Upload button says "Upload another file"

Does anyone have any suggestions about what I could do to find out more about why it doesn't work and to fix the problem? I don't think it's my .apk as it also fails with an older .apk that I used in the past.

Is there a place I can go to find more information or another way I can do it so I can see what the issue is?

Comment: This question is not coding related. You should either provide more info or contact [support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en)

Comment: Developer console issue . Not coding related.

Comment: What do you mean "Developer console issue".  I'm using Google Play web site and clicking on the upload button.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem in Google Chroms browser by:

1. going to: developer console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) > Application > Clear storage > Clear site data
2. pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> to refrash the page
3. re-uploading the app